# Unitils @SpringApplicationContext - how to find time taken to initialize spring context?

Tags: spring, unitils

I am using unitils for testing. I see more than 90 spring context refresh messages in the failsafe test reports. I need to know how much time is taken to initialize these spring contexts. 
Unitils does not have proper logging, so not able to track it with framework logs.

The `@SpringApplicationContext` is on top of the test class, so cannot go for logger in my own test class

Writing an advice or aware class or an interceptor will not help, as all these classes has to be registered in the spring xml and those beans which are registered in spring xml will be loaded only after the context is initialized

Writing an application listener class, we can catch only the `ContextRefreshedEvent`, that is when the context in loaded not initialized.

Cannot catch the `ContextStartedEvent` because it is published when the ApplicationContext is started using the `start()` method on the `ConfigurableApplicationContext interface`. Whereas unitils dynamically creates new `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(..,..);` to create the spring context `(class:org.unitils.spring.util.ClassPathXmlApplicationContextFactory)`

How do I calculate spring context initialization time?

Answer (score 0):

What about simple log4j logger? When logging Spring info logs you can see ContexLoader initialization time.

17:25:48 INFO - ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started

17:25:53 INFO - ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 5325 ms

Comment: The spring context is being created by unitils in the class `ClassPathXmlApplicationContextFactory` (which is from unitils) below is the code extract `public ConfigurableApplicationContext createApplicationContext(List<String> locations) {
        return new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(locations.toArray(new String[locations.size()]), false);
    }` and in the `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` constructor (which is from spring), ther is no log info. so, I dont see the log message for context initialization.